# How to properly write C structure to file on disk, so it was possible to use mmap on it?

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, mmap, memory-alignment

I use following C structure in memory:

```c
typedef struct MyStructHdr
{

    char        text[4];
    int         version_num;

    uint64 init_value;

    uint64 entries[];

} MyStructHdr;

typedef MyStructHdr *MyStruct;
```

Field `entries[]` is a pointer to some flexible array. Type `uint64` is a custom portable application specific type, which add `uint64_t` support on 32-bit OS.

I have to properly write this structure to file, so that I was able to use `mmap()` on it later (on the same platform/OS):

```c
map = (MyStruct) mmap(NULL, MyStructActualSize,
                      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                      mystruct_fd, 0);
```

What I do now? I simply write `MyStruct` fields one by one (and `entries[]` by chunks via buffer) using `write()`. At the end `CRC32` checksum is written.

Everything works just fine on all available to me 64-bit systems. It seems that first 4 chars + 32-bit `int` are aligned into the single 64-bit chunk and `uint64` simply expands into `uint64_t`, so after write everything is `mmap`'ed correctly.

However, I am afraid that on 32-bit system or some specific OS/architecture, where different alignment rules are applied and there is no `uint64_t` and `uint64` expands into something like:

```c
{
    int val1;
    unsigned long int val2;
}
```

I will get incorrect `mmap`'ing after write.

What is a portable way to write such a structure to file and use `mmap` after that?

P.S. Actually, this is all about PostgreSQL extension and `uint64` here is `pg_atomic_uint64`, but I think that question is more general.

Comment: A flexible array member is not a pointer. It's a name for an array that follows the structure immediately in memory.

Comment: In general, you can't use binary data portably between different architectures. There can be alignment and endianness differences.

Comment: Yep, maybe I wrote it a bit vague. I mean `MyStruct->entries` is a beginning of some flexible array.

Comment: You can only mmap it if you're doing it on the same architecture that you wrote the file.

Comment: No, I want to write/mmap on the same platform, not to share the file between them. I want a portable code.

Comment: Where do you specify the length of the flexible array? Is that `init_value`?

Comment: No, its size is limited by the configuration of my application. What matters is that I know its size exactly when my program starts.

Comment: Why don't you just `mmap()` the file, write your data to the mapped region, and let your system kernel dump it to the file? If you then `mmap()` the same file for reading (using the same data structure on the same architecture), you are guaranteed that the data won't be screwed up.

Comment: Yes, but this structure is concurrently accessed and I want to write a checksum at the end. That way, if I simply sync the mmap'ed region I will get some unpredictable state.

Comment: @ololobus: So mmap the file in a separate place and copy the struct into the mapped region (with appropriate locking or atomic operations).  If you need to ensure that certain pieces hit the filesystem before others, there's `msync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write the members one by one, because that won't account for padding between members. Write the whole thing all at once:

```
write(fd, MyStruct, sizeof(MyStructHdr) + entry_count * sizeof(uint64));
```

where `entry_count` is the number of elements in the flexible array member.

If you need to write each member separately for atomicity, you can use the `offsetof` macro to get the size including padding.

```
write(fd, &MyStruct->text, offsetof(MyStructHdr, version_num));
write(fd, &Mystruct->version_num, offsetof(MyStructHdr, init_value) - offsetof(MyStructHdr, version_num));
write(fd, &MyStruct->init_value, offsetof(MyStructHdr, entries) - offsetof(MyStructHdr, init_value));
```

then write the `MyStruct->entries` array in chunks. You don't need to worry about padding there, because `sizeof` on an array element includes the padding between elements (this ensures that `sizeof array == element_count * sizeof array[0]`);

Comment: This would work, but unfortunately, this piece of memory is concurrently accessed and I cannot lock it entirely due to the performance reasons, so I use atomic operations with `uint64`. So the questions is, how can I reproduce memory alignment rules, but when writing data to file? E.g. I could write one `int32_t` + 32 zero bits and so on.

Comment: Can you write the header in one step and then write the entries in a loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to write it one member at a time to account for padding.

Comment: @ololobus: Could you make your own private copy of the struct (atomically, one member at a time), and then write out the private copy?

Comment: Note that if you don't lock the whole struct when copying or writing, you may get inconsistent data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for a late response. It worked just fine for me.